# First Query Doesn't Fully Execute

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a ticket system and need to have a couple of queries, and I am getting the following error.

> PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given

The line is pointing to I added a comment next to below. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM stix_cart WHERE confirmation = '$confirmation'";
$result = mysql_query($check);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    error_log(mysql_error());
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO stix_orders (
                paymethod,
                confirmation,
                payer_first,
                payer_last,
                startorder,
                endorder,
                name,
                code,
                qty,
                price,
                original,
                puname,
                txn_id)
            VALUES (
                'paypal',
                '".$row['confirmation']."',
                '".$row['payer_first']."',
                '".$row['payer_last']."',
                '".$row['timestamp']."',
                '".$currenttime."',
                '".$row['name']."',
                ".$row['code'].",
                ".$row['qty'].",
                ".$row['price'].",
                ".$row['original'].",
                '".$row['puname']."',
                '".$txn_id."')";

        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
            error_log(mysql_error());
            exit(0);
        }

        $confirmation = $row['confirmation'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $code = $row['code'];


        $ticketcheck = 'SELECT MAX(ticket_number) AS max_number FROM stix_tickets WHERE item_number = $row[code]';
        $resulttix = mysql_query($ticketcheck);
        if ($resulttix === FALSE) {
            $incnumber = 1;
        }

        while($ticketrow = mysql_fetch_array($resulttix)) { // This line
            $incnumber = $ticketrow['max_number'] + 1;

            for ($i=1; $i <= $itemqty; $i++) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO stix_tickets (
                        txn_id,
                        confirmation,
                        item_name,
                        item_number,
                        ticket_number)
                    VALUES (
                        '".$txn_id."',
                        '".$confirmation."',
                        '".$name."',
                        ".$code.",
                        ".$incnumber.")";
                $incnumber++;

                if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
                    error_log(mysql_error());
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query is failing, did you check the error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is failing here

```
$ticketcheck = 'SELECT MAX(ticket_number) AS max_number FROM stix_tickets WHERE item_number = $row[code]';
```

That is because .. Variables under single quotes will not be parsed !

Change it like ...

```
$ticketcheck = "SELECT MAX(ticket_number) AS `max_number` FROM `stix_tickets` WHERE item_number = '".$row['code']."'";
```

**`SideNote`**

The (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead,the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: or simply `$ticketcheck = "SELECT MAX(ticket_number) AS max_number FROM stix_tickets WHERE item_number = $row[code]";`

Comment: Yeah @maackle **+1** and I don't wanna confuse the OP with a lot possibilities ;)

Comment: the `item_number = '1234'` won't work if `item_number` isn't a string or will it?

Comment: @SSpoke, Yeah it will .. It's a fail-safe solution.

Comment: Wow you are right it works, who knew strange I remember ages ago it didn't work maybe my memory is just fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

This how I would fix it.

```
$ticketcheck = "SELECT MAX(ticket_number) AS max_number FROM stix_tickets WHERE item_number = '{$row['code']}'";
```

Use the curly brackets for all your arrays in queries.
Here is more information about this
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex